# Why does NumberFormatter format 19,999,999,999,999,999 to 20,000,000,000,000,000 in Swift?

Tags: swift

I need to separate `Int` values with commas every 3 digits in Swift.
I have tried to do this with `NumberFormatter`, but it sometimes returns unexpected results with large digits.
Why is this?

```swift
import Foundation

func format(_ num: Int) -> String {
  let formatter = NumberFormatter()
  formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
  formatter.groupingSeparator = ","
  formatter.groupingSize = 3
  return formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: num)) ?? String(num)
}

let num1 =       199_999_999_999_999
let num2 =     1_999_999_999_999_999
let num3 =    19_999_999_999_999_999
let num4 =   199_999_999_999_999_999
let num5 = 1_999_999_999_999_999_999

print(format(num1))
print(format(num2))
print(format(num3))
print(format(num4))
print(format(num5))

// 199,999,999,999,999
// 1,999,999,999,999,999
// 20,000,000,000,000,000 <- unexpected results
// 199,999,999,999,999,999
// 1,999,999,999,999,999,999
```

Comment: Probably has to do with the rounding that happens with large numbers in floating point respresentations. I’m surprised it does effect all the larger numbers though

Comment: @Alexander These are Ints. Where is the "floating point"? Either this is within the Int range or it isn't.

Comment: @matt I figured NSNumberFormatter might be using a double internally to support the wide range of inputs that it’s compatible with.

Comment: @Alexander It's using NSNumber for sure, but it's not NSNumber's fault. I can't reproduce the issue _except_ when passing through an NSNumberFormatter, at which point the flaw is very obvious in many values in the neighborhood of the problematic one.  The value is passing to the called method correctly; it's only the number formatter that is messing it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in NumberFormatter. (There are many.) Try printing `Decimal(19_999_999_999_999_999).formatted()` instead.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I still need to support iOS 14.

Comment: Well, since your needs are so simple, you could just write your own formatter.